# How to simplify the `str.title()` at multiple columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my first question in StackOverflow.

Please, can somebody help me explain if there is any way to simplify the code with `str.title()` in multiple columns simultaneously?

Here is my code:

```
df['name'] = df['booking_type'].str.title()
df['status'] = df['status'].str.title()
df['type'] = df['type'].str.title()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Series.str` functions are Series only, so there isn't a great way of applying them to multiple columns simultaneously.

Most efficient is probably just putting them in a for-loop. If you really want to, you can use `applymap` to apply a function to all cells, but this is likely slower than the column-based approach.

```
for col in ('name', 'status', 'type'):
    df[col] = df[col].str.title()
# OR
df[['name', 'status', 'type']] = df[['name', 'status', 'type']].applymap(str.title)
```